# In Java, how can I read a text file consisting of "word<space>number<space>number"?

Tags: java, file, text, bufferedreader, stringtokenizer

I have a text file with these type of values (an example):

```
5 Dog 23 45 Cat 97 23 Mouse 13 23 Bird 10 23 Dog 99 18
```

The first digit '5' is the total number of array objects that I need to tokenize. I want it so that when I tokenize the text file, it ignores '5' then reads them as:

```
Dog 23 45
Cat 97 23
Mouse 13 23
Bird 10 23
Dog 99 18
```

and then put all the same objects together in an array. So for example the dog arraylist would have:

```
Dog 23 45
Dog 99 18
```

I just want to know how I can tokenize a word followed by two numbers with spaces. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Think about the pattern.  You have a numeral indicating the number of entries you have.  Then you have a string, followed by two integer values.  I'd encourage you to start thinking about how you'd want to break that up (at the bare minimum, I could see a `while` loop in this code).

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.io.BufferedReader to read a file line by line.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/file.txt"));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
// ...
}
```

Tutorial: Basic I/O > I/O Streams > Character Streams

You can use String#split() to split a String in parts.

```
String[] parts = line.split("\\s");
```

Tutorial: Numbers and Strings > Strings > Manipulating Characters in a String

You can use an enhanced for loop to iterate over String parts.

```
for (String part : parts) {
    // ...
}
```

Tutorial: Language Basics > Control Flow Statements > The for Statement

You can use Integer#valueOf() to convert a String into an Integer.

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(part);
```

Tutorial: Interfaces > The List Interface

You can use List#add() to add an element to a List.

```
list.add(i);
```

Tutorial: Trial: Collections

Answer (score 0):

With pattern:

```
@Test
public void testPattern() {
    String value = "5 Dog 23 45 Cat 97 23 Mouse 13 23 Bird 10 23 Dog 99 18";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\D+)\\d+\\s++\\d+").matcher(value);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group() + ": " + matcher.group(1));
    }

}
```

Output is:

```
 Dog 23 45:  Dog 
 Cat 97 23:  Cat 
 Mouse 13 23:  Mouse 
 Bird 10 23:  Bird 
 Dog 99 18:  Dog
```